# Python - установка lxml - ошибка с vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, python-3.x

пытаюcь установить `lxml`, но всегда выдает ошибку, пробовал через `pip` и через `easy_install`. Подскажите как установить эту библиотеку на 3 версию `Python`

*Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 - установлена*

*Python 3.5.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение:

скачиваем файл `.whl` с http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, и устанавливаем через `pip`:

```
pip install lxml-3.5.0-cp35-none-win32.whl
```